# Ajax not woking on wordpress front

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Im having an issue with calling ajax from front of my wordpress site The data just dose not go through to the other file when the ajax is called on change. The value in ajax `this.value` is passed ok from .

```php
<?php
function my_enqueue()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-ajax-script.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue');
....
<script>
    jQuery('#courseid').on('change', function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/inc/ssc/public_ajax_options_topics.php',
            data: {
                action: 'g6_options_topics',
                product_id: this.value
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            jQuery("#topicid").html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the file that response is send to

```php
<?php
require_once('../../../../../wp-load.php');

$mysqli = db();
$product_id = 0;
if ($_POST['product_id']) {
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
}
```

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase Nothing happens link the value is not passed. I don't have access to the ``$_POST['product_id']`` I have tried changing the url param action etc. Im on this issue for 2 days now... Any help is welcome :)

Comment: If nothing happens, what have you tried to debug **why** nothing happens? I think this means, the AJAX call isn't even sent to the backend? Is there any error message written to your browser's console?

Comment: @NicoHaase No errors in the console. I can see the value in the network tab. I tried adding a hook to the receiving file with the action name but still nothing. I think this has to do with the way wordpress handles ajax calls and that i'm doing something wrong

Comment: If you localized the script and made a name for admin-ajax.php how come you're not using it?

Comment: Why are you using `action`? if you are not calling WordPress ajax.